# string.prototype.search('$') returns positive int on every string

Tags: javascript, string

I want to check if a `string` contains any of several symbols, including `'$'`. But the `string.prototype.search()` method returns last character index + 1 when searching for `'$'`

For example:

```
'abc'.search('$')   //return 3
''.search('$')      //return 0
```

I want to know why this is happening

Comment: `String.prototype.search` uses Regular Expressions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search - I think you're looking for `String.prototype.indexOf`

Comment: $ matches the end of the string, and search returns the position of a match

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search):

> **regexp**
>   Optional. A regular expression object. If a non-RegExp object `obj` is passed, it is implicitly converted to a `RegExp` by using `new RegExp(obj)`.

So your call is equivalent to:

```
'abc'.search(/$/);
```

`$` in a regular expression matches the end of the string. If you want to disable the special meaning, you need to escape it:

```
'abc'.search('\\$')
```

You need two `\` characters: the first escapes the backslash in the string literal, and this then escapes the dollar sign in the regexp. Or you could write:

```
'abc'.search(/\$/)
```